# Angularjs validation are showing Error meassage even after validate

Tags: angularjs, angular-validation

Here why my validation are not working
what wrong I'm doing pllease help me

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrls">
    <form novalidate name="f1" ng-submit="SaveData(User)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email address:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="log_email" ng-model="User.Email" required>

            <span ng-show="(f1.log_email.$error.required) && f1.log_email.$dirty) ||(f1.log_email.$touch)">Please Enter Your Email</span>

        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your condition should be

```
ng-show="(f1.log_email.$error.required && f1.log_email.$dirty) ||(f1.log_email.$error.required && f1.log_email.$touched)"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be $touched rather than $touch ?